# Is my home temp endangering hermit crabs

Tags: health, molting, hermit-crabs

I have 3 hermit crabs (5 months). Two of my crabs buried themselves 1 month ago and there is no dead smell. Our home is kept 69 degrees day and 67 night. How do I know my crabs are not dying a slow painful death and not molting? I really worry about this.